# How to solve the pure render/function binding pr0blem in vanilla React?

Tags: performance, reactjs

Let's start with some code:

```
export default class BookingDriverContainer extends React.PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        bookingId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            saving: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ajax(Router.route('api.bookingDrivers', {
            id: this.props.bookingId,
        })).then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    segments: res.data.segments,
                    drivers: res.data.drivers,
                });
            }
        });
    }

    driverChanged = segmentId => ev => {
        console.log(`Driver for segment ${segmentId} changed to ${ev.target.value}`);    
    };

    render() {
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <img src={loadingGif} width="220" height="20" alt="Loading..."/>;
        }

        return (
            <table className="index-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{width: '50px'}}>Seg.</th>
                        <th style={{width: '70px'}}>Unit</th>
                        <th style={{width: '140px'}}>Driver</th>
                        <th style={{width: '100px'}}>Driver #</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.segments.map(seg => (
                        <tr key={seg.id}>
                            <td>*snip*</td>
                            <td>*snip*</td>
                            <td>
                                <SelectBox onChange={this.driverChanged(seg.id)}>
                                    <option value="" className="not-set">TBD</option>
                                    {this.state.drivers.map(([id, name]) => (
                                        <option key={id} value={id}>{name}</option>
                                    ))}
                                </SelectBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>*snip*</td>
                            <td>*snip*</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

In this example, my component is *not* pure because of this: `onChange={this.driverChanged(seg.id)}`. i.e., every time my component renders, that creates a new function, which will cause `<SelectBox>` to be re-rendered even though nothing has changed.

How can this be fixed without introducing a large framework like Redux?

Comment: the thing is `onChange={this.driverChanged(seg.id)}` is running at the very start and using whatever it returned as the value/function. You should change it to `onChange={this.driverChanged.bind(this,seg.id)}` or `onChange={() => this.driverChanged(seg.id)}` Or is that what you want?

Comment: @A.Lau Notice the two arrows in the function definition: `driverChanged = segmentId => ev => {`. It's implicitly creating a binding the way I did it; I just prefer it this way, I think it looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to prevent creating new functions every time the component renders, you could simply create another component to contain `SelectBox` component:

```
class MySelectBox extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    drivers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    segId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    driverChanged: PropTypes.function.isRequired,
  }
  render() {
    const {
      drivers,
      segId,
      driverChanged,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <SelectBox onChange={ev => driverChanged(ev, segId)}>
          <option value="" className="not-set">TBD</option>
          {drivers.map(([id, name]) => (
              <option key={id} value={id}>{name}</option>
          ))}
      </SelectBox>
    );
  }
}
```

Then use this new component inside `BookingDriverContainer` with the proper properties:

```
export default class BookingDriverContainer extends React.Component {
  // ...
  driverChanged = (ev, segId) => {
    console.log(`Driver for segment ${segId} changed to ${ev.target.value}`);
  }
  render() {
    // ...

    return (
      <table className="index-table">
        <thead>
          {/* ... */}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.segments.map(seg => (
            <tr key={seg.id}>
              <td>*snip*</td>
              <td>*snip*</td>
              <td>
                <MySelectBox
                  driverChanged={this.driverChanged}
                  segId={seg.id}
                  drivers={this.state.drivers}
                />
              </td>
              <td>*snip*</td>
              <td>*snip*</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

This way you do not create new functions at every render times.

Comment: Right, but `driverChanged` is going to change state on `BookingDriverContainer`. If I move the function definition to the subcomponent (not that I want to do that, because it makes it not re-usable) I can no longer call `this.setState`. If I want to manipulate the state of the parent component from `<SelectBox>` I'd have to pass through another function, but then we're back to where we were unless I use one property for the function, and separate props for each argument, but that is an insane amount of boilerplate to avoid this problem.

Comment: @mpen updated, I moved the `driverChanged` function back to parent component

Comment: Don't think you can do `onChange={ev => driverChanged(ev, segId)}` -- that's the exact same problem: you're creating a *new* function every time that's rendered. In other words, `(ev => f(ev)) !== (ev => f(ev))`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I've found so far is just to memoize the function.

```
driverChanged = memoize(segmentId => ev => {
    // ...
});
```

This way, given the same `segmentId` it will return the same function instance, which will allow the `PureRenderMixin` et al. to work their magic.

Here's my memoize function:

```
export default function memoize(fn, options={
    serialize: fn.length === 1 ? x => x : (...args) => JSON.stringify(args),
}) {
    let cache = new Map();
    return (...args) => {
        let key = options.serialize(...args);
        if(cache.has(key)) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
        let value = fn(...args);
        cache.set(key, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

It only supports JSON-serializable variables, but you can find a more advanced memoizer on npm if you wish.